# XGO failing to cross-compile with file/directory not found

Tags: docker, go, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile my [Golang project](https://github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go), and I found [xgo](https://github.com/techknowlogick/xgo) to be a useful tool for doing this (the project link is an updated version). After running the commands to set up the Docker container and install `xgo` onto my environment, I tried running the following command:

`GO111MODULE=on /Users/bli24/go/bin/xgo github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go`

However, I seem to keep getting this error at the end of my console output:

```
bli24@macbook-air-2 Downloads % GO111MODULE=on /Users/bli24/go/bin/xgo github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go 
Checking docker installation...
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.11
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.10
 Git commit:        dea9396
 Built:             Thu Nov 18 00:36:09 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.11
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.9
  Git commit:       847da18
  Built:            Thu Nov 18 00:35:39 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

Checking for required docker image techknowlogick/xgo:latest... found.
Cross compiling github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go...
Fetching main repository github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go...
go: downloading github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go v0.0.0-20211227013202-ebbb4e4c77c6
/build.sh: line 91: cd: /go/src/github.com/MinecraftMediaLibrary/EzMediaCore-Native-Go: No such file or directory
2021/12/28 17:05:30 Failed to cross compile package: exit status 1.
```

I have tried for other projects such as `github.com/project-iris/iris` for the project URL, but I still seem to get the `No such file or directory` at the end. The reason why I am using `xgo` to compile is because my project uses the `C` import, and I am compiling it to be a `c-shared library`.